# iOS App update new screen images with old images

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I updated new version of app in apple store with new images but unable to update that images on apple store still showing old app screens app already approved with new updated images.
i can show new images in my iTunes connect account but when i search my app on apple store still show old version images.
App already approved by apple

Answer (score 1):

The screenshots need time to change in the AppStore, about 1-2 hours.

Comment: app approved one week ago still not changed